# How to reload ASP.NET user profile data

Tags: c#, asp.net, profile

This feels like a basic question, but I'm still new.

I am passing ASP.NET TextBox control values (e.g. user's name, bio etc) to a page method in my code-behind and then saving these to the user's Profile. This all appears to be working fine.

```
[WebMethod]
public static void UpdateProfile(Person formValues)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Profile.SetPropertyValue("Bio", formValues.Bio);
}
```

(Note - formValues is being supplied from an AJAX Post through jQuery).

I would like to see the updated profile information actually reflected on the ASPX web form without having to manually refresh the page to get the recently updated Profile information. Is this possible?

Here's what I am doing in my Page_Load method

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        FirstName.Text = Profile.FirstName;
        Bio.Text = Profile.Bio;

    }
}
```

I hope this make sense.
Thank you.

Comment: It does make sense - if your actual display is in another UpdatePanel, for example, then you could force that UpdatePanel to refresh, causing it to reload the user profile data. Other strategies might include updating the text on the page directly, via JavaScript. To help definitively, would be useful to know if your profile display is hosted within an UpdatePanel.

Comment: @dash Thanks for your reply. Yes, the current profile is displayed in an UpdatePanel and I was trying to get it to refresh. I did also think about updating the controls via JavaScript too, but I shall get on see if the UpdatePanel approach gives me what I want. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Following dash's suggestion and doing some further reading, I implemented what seemed like a simple approach: to add a hidden Button to the `UpdatePanel` and then call the onclick for the hidden Button from jQuery.

(Did I mention that the updated Profile information was being collected through a jQuery UI dialog?)

**Here's the relevant ASPX code:**

```
    <!-- Change User Profile info -->
    <div id="profileBasicInfoDiv">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="True" UpdateMode="Conditional" Visible="True">
             <ContentTemplate>       
                 <asp:Label ID="lblProfileUserName" runat="server" Text="Name"></asp:Label>
                 <asp:Button ID="btnUserProfileUpdatePanel1" runat="server" Text="Button" Visible="True" onclick="btnUserProfileUpdatePanel1_Click" />        
            </ContentTemplate>     
       </asp:UpdatePanel>
       <br /> 
       <a href="#" id="hlShowBasicInfo">Change my details</a>
   </div> <!-- End of profileBasicInfoDiv -->
```

**..the jQuery:**

```
 $("#profileChangeBasicInfo").dialog({
            modal: true,
            buttons: { 'Save': function () { $(this).dialog('close'); }                    
            },
            close: function () { UpdateProfile(); }

        });
 function UpdateProfile() {

        var jsonText = "{'Bio':'" + $("[id$='MainContent_Bio']").val() + "','FirstName':'" + $("[id$='MainContent_FirstName']").val() + "'} ";
        sendData(jsonText);
        $("#MainContent_btnUserProfileUpdatePanel1").click();

    };
```

**And here's the corresponding onclick event handler for the hidden button:**

```
  protected void btnUserProfileUpdatePanel1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        UpdatePanel1.Update();
        ((Label)(lblProfileUserName)).Text = Profile.FirstName + " " + Profile.LastName;
   }
```

This might not be the most elegant method, but it's working and I have learnt quite a lot along the way. Your thoughts and comments are greatly appreciated.

Thank you.